# C# EntityFrameWork problem when trying to post to database (Invalid column name)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework-6

This is the first question I ask here so I will try to give all the information I can.
I searched the web for 5 days and using ChatGPT as well but I couldn't fix the problem unfortunately.
I built a database in SQL and when trying to post to the table 'Error' (using c#) using Postman I get an error that 'MoldID' is invalid column name.

I created a 'Class Library' project and added a new item 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model' to it. After that I created a WEB API project, downloaded ENTITY FRAMEWORK to it and referenced the 'Class Library' project to the web api project where all the controllers are.

I have sent this in postman through body :
{
"description": "Problem1",
"type": "Break1",
"technicianID": "2",
"MoldID": "18164"
};

Here is my sql code for 'Error' table :

```
CREATE TABLE Error (
ErrorNumber INT PRIMARY KEY,
OpeningDate DATETIME,
ClosingDate DATETIME,
TreatmentHours DECIMAL(10,2),
Description NVARCHAR(255),
Type NVARCHAR(50),
TechnicianID INT,
PriorityID INT,
MoldID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (TechnicianID) REFERENCES Technician(EmployeeNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (PriorityID) REFERENCES Priority(PriorityID),
FOREIGN KEY (MoldID) REFERENCES Mold(MoldID)
);
```

Here is the controller that sends the post :

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/error/new")]
        public IHttpActionResult AddError(AddErrorModel model)
        {
            string description = model.Description;
            string type = model.Type;
            int technicianId = model.TechnicianID;
            int moldID = model.MoldID;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
            {
                return BadRequest("Description and Type cannot be empty.");
            }

            // Create a new Error object and set the properties
            Error error = new Error
            {
                Description = description,
                Type = type,
                TechnicianID = technicianId,
                OpeningDate = DateTime.Now,
                ClosingDate = null,
                TreatmentHours = null,
                PriorityID = null,
                MoldID = moldID,
            };

            // Add the new Error object to the database and save the changes
            db.Errors.Add(error);
            db.SaveChanges();

            string location = Url.Route("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Error", id = error.ErrorNumber });
            return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri, location), error);
        }
    }
```

Here is the auto-generated 'Error' class :

```
    public partial class Error
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Error()
        {
            this.StatusErrors = new HashSet<StatusError>();
        }
    
        public int ErrorNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OpeningDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ClosingDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> TreatmentHours { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TechnicianID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PriorityID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> MoldID { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Mold Mold { get; set; }
        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
        public virtual Technician Technician { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<StatusError> StatusErrors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the context class :

```
namespace DATA
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class NetafimDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public NetafimDbContext()
            : base("name=NetafimDbContext")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Error> Errors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<InjectionTechnician> InjectionTechnicians { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Mold> Molds { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MoldRoomTechnician> MoldRoomTechnicians { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Priority> Priorities { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SchedulingConstraint> SchedulingConstraints { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StatusError> StatusErrors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StatusErrorStageEnum> StatusErrorStageEnums { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Technician> Technicians { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I really hope that I explained myself good enough and provided enough data in order to receive help from you all, if there is anything missing or I forgot something please let me know !

I tried to save data in my SQL table named 'Error' using postman and c# controller.
I tried to add [ForeignKey("MoldID")] abode MoldID in the 'Error' class and than ctrl + s but it didn't work.
Picture of the .edmx diagram :
[.edmx Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1xV2.png)

Edit :
Here is the 'AddErrorModel' class :

```
public class AddErrorModel
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int TechnicianID { get; set; }
        public int MoldID { get; set; }
    };
```

And when I debug in my C# I get thrown in `db.SaveChanges();`
This is the object 'error' when I look at it with debug in `db.Errors.Add(error)` - [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5q23.png) , and this is the exception in C# - `SqlException: Invalid column name 'MoldID'.`

Comment: Did you check the MySQL log file?  See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html

Comment: Are you receiving error in postman or when saving the new entity at `db.SaveChanges();`? Have you tried placing a breakpoint inside AddError API method and see if you even reached that stage? What is the structure of class `AddErrorModel` ? Maybe you mispelled the column name there?

Comment: Have you tried sending an int rather than a string for MoldID in your Postman body?

Comment: @AgasiMkhitaryan The error occurs when trying to save the new entity at `db.SaveChanges();` , this is the 'AddErrorModel' class : 

`public class AddErrorModel
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int TechnicianID { get; set; }
        public int MoldID { get; set; }
    };` .

I have checked if I misspelled in my SQL or in C# but the names are all the same.. 'MoldID' .
@SoftwareDveloper yes I tried sending an int in postman but I received the same error message.  
@jdweng I don't understand how..

Comment: Double-check that the database connection string at runtime is pointing at the same database instance you are checking because especially if things get moved around between projects it will be pulling connection strings from the web.config not a DLL app.config. Add the following line somewhere before the SaveChanges with a breakpoint: 'var connectionString = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;` Check that this is pointing at where you think it should be going. It may be pointing at an older DB Schema that lacks your Mold association.

Comment: After many headaches I just made a new project, did the exact same steps and it works... I have no idea why or what happened but now it is working ! Thank you for the help everyone I really appreciate it!